# C++/C: Setting up local HTTPS proxy server for rerouting

Tags: ssl, https, proxy, server, router

I've read quite a few SO questions such as this one:

[Local HTTPS proxy possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512521/local-https-proxy-possible)

**Setup**: I have one machine, "A", that can be accessed externally, and server machines, "B", that share an internal network with "A" and aren't exposed to the Internet.

**Task**: I want to set up a local, bidirectional HTTPS proxy server on "A" that simply *reroutes* incoming HTTPS packets to "B" and response packets from "B" back out to the source without using open source solutions. Basically a local router.

**Problem**: It seems to be the consensus that it isn't possible to modify the headers of incoming packets without messing up the CA certs

**Questions**:

1. Is there a clean way to achieve the task?
2. How does an everyday, in-your-house router reroute HTTPS packets without messing up the CA certs?

I'm completely new to networking, so bear with me if these are simple questions.