# GoogleMaps API usage through proxy

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I'd like to access the GoogleMaps API inside a proxy using

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY"> </script>
```

from a web application.

Is there other way to use this service than add an exception to the proxy?
If not what urls have to be added to the exception?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

As it is a https connection it will not allow proxies due to its security. Take a look at this StackOverflow thread [HTTPS connections over proxy servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516323/https-connections-over-proxy-servers). It has more details on this and some possible workarounds.